# Submiting form using turbolinks from javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csrf, turbolinks

Is it possible to submit form from javascript using Turbolinks ? I have form with remote:true but i dont want to send it when submit button is clicked, instead i want to use ordinary button that is outside the form that will send it on click. Is it possible to submit form from js without crazy cheats like simulating click on "submit button" ? I dont want to use manual ajax because then i need to build xhr request for each form and attach somehow CRSF token to it.

If i try to do it by

```
$("#form").submit()
```

I get

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

which is propably cross forgery problem

but I have in my application.html.erb

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

but submitting using jquery doesnt attach token because its xhr...

Or maybe there is a easy way to just attach token to .submit() ?

**EDIT 1:**

I added this to my form

```
<input name="authenticity_token" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
```

and works

but now submiting form like `$(form).submit()`, sends it twice with turbolinks... Seems like turbolinks runs and after it normal submit is permorming and site is reload. I guess the more I try cooperate between turbolinks and ordinary js the more problems I find

form.html.erb

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), remote: true) do |f| %>
<input name="authenticity_token" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>"/>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div data-behavior="devise-error-messages">
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
</div>
<div data-behavior="flashes">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <%= flash[:error] %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

<!--  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div> -->
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
    <button id="sign_up">Sign up</button>
</div>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

app.js

```
$(document).on("ready", function(e){


$(document).on("submit", "#new_user", function(e){


    console.log(e);


});

$(document).on("click", "#sign_up", function(e){

    $("#new_user").submit();


})

});
```

**EDIT 2**
so I changed my click event to this

```
$(document).on("click", "#sign_up", function(e){

 var elem = document.getElementById('new_user') 
 Rails.fire(elem, 'submit');
 console.log("sign up click");
})
```

Now it works and form submits once.

Another problem with turbolinks is that when I successfuly sign_up I generate javascript with `Turbolinks.visit("/user_after_signed_up")`

I wanted to prevent back button so, i cant back to my login form, so i turned of cache adding this to application.html:
 `<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">`

Guess what, not working.

in my routes i redirect authenticated users to dashboard if they want to access 'login form', but with turbolinks, when u click back 'address change' and turbolinks serve cached version.

IM NOT ABLE TO TURN OFF this cache, I also tried

`Turbolinks.cacheClear()`

in several places and still doesnt work.

**EDIT 3**

combining both actually make it works
add this to application.html
`<meta name="turbolinks-cache-control" content="no-cache">`
and this in rendered js

`Turbolinks.cacheClear()` before `Turbolinks.visit("/path_to_redirect")`

But it seems unlogic to clear cache where there suppose to be no caching at all...

Comment: Post your form code and the html it generates.